# Converting struct headers to and from vec<char>

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to pack a message buffer vector with smaller messages of char* interleaved along with their respective headers. These headers are cast as char* from a struct. A receiver unpacks the buffers by jumping from header to header. Using the header, they can identify the size of the corresponding message and at which position the next header starts.

```
struct header_t {
  uint64_t src : 16;
  uint64_t dst : 16;
  uint64_t len : 32;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

This is a fixed-size header struct. They are converted to a vector using using :

```
std::vector<char> pack_header(int src, int dest, int data_size){
    header_t hdr_struct{(uint64_t)src, (uint64_t)dest, (uint64_t)data_size};
    char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hdr_struct);
    std::vector<char> hdr = std::vector<char>(ptr, ptr + sizeof(header_t));

    return hdr;
  }
```

The main packs 3 messages along with their respective headers by appending them to the buffer. For simplicity, I also call the unpacking function here but in the real app, the buffers are unpacked at some other process.

```
int main()
{
    auto header1 = pack_header(2, 4, 43);
    auto header2 = pack_header(2, 4, 29);
    auto header3 = pack_header(2, 4, 23);
//Test messages of the given sizes
    char* data1 = new char[43]();
    char* data2 = new char[29]();
    char* data3 = new char[23]();
    
//messages interleaved with headers
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), header1.begin(),header1.end());
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), data1, data1+43);
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), header2.begin(),header2.end());
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), data2, data2+29);
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), header3.begin(),header3.end());
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), data3, data3+23);
    

    unpack(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

This unpacks function iterates through the buffer by taking steps in the size of header length(8 bytes) + message length.

```
  void unpack(std::vector<char> &stream)
  {
    char* bitr = &stream[0];
    int step =0;
    std::vector<header_t*> hdr_stream;

    while(step <= stream.size())
    {
        std::cout<<"\nstep: "<<step;
        header_t header;
        memcpy(&header, bitr, sizeof(header_t));
        std::cout<<"\nlen_after : "<<header.len<<"\n";
        step+=header.len + sizeof(header_t);
        bitr+=step;
 
    }

  }
```

The unpack function steps through the first 2 messages correctly but loses its way after that and doesn't infer the headers. The output looks like this :

```
step: 0
message length : 43

step: 51
message length : 29

step: 88
message length : 0

step: 96
message length : 0

step: 104
message length : 0

step: 112
message length : 0
```

Any reasons why it couldn't correctly infer the size from the headers after the second message. It just reads the size as 0 and steps over headers rather than header + messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every iteration, you increment `step` by the size of the current packet. It is an index into `stream` of where the next packet starts. However, you add to `bitr` this index, resulting in Undefined Behavior because `bitr` has been increased past the end of the buffer.

What you get is:

```
start of 1st loop: bitr = 0
start of 2nd loop: bitr = 51 (size of first packet)
start of 3rd loop: bitr = 139 (51 + 51 + 37, 2 * size of first packet + size of second packet)
```

What you want to do is increment `bitr` the same amount you increase `step` (`bitr+=header.len + sizeof(header_t);`), or set set `bitr` to the newly computed index (`bitr = &stream[step];`).

Comment: Yup that is exactly it. As a follow-up in the unpacking function, can I directly reinterpret the pointer to the buffer stream as a struct rather than copying each header into a separate object. Kinda like the reverse of how I pack it. I am wary as I might be violating the strict aliasing. I know it is not a problem for converting struct to char* but not the other way.